# error: disk lvmid/... not found Entering rescue mode

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, boot, grub

I deleted the partition containing Fedora to install Ubuntu (in Win 10), but after I rebooted I'm getting the following error message: `"error: disk 'lvmid/Xe53HM-hHmX-fDKu-BCLf-Oa9w-n4Dt-7f9UdA/WE42Po-BN7m-Og4c-LTcX-zVN7-cTJm-sMdNzo' not found" entering rescue mode`.

I think I lost my bootloader. How to recover the bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem after deleting my Xubuntu 16.04 installation from a Win10 pre-installed laptop.
You have to restore the Windows Boot Loader, because GRUB replaced it. If you have a Win10-Installation-Media (like an Install-CD/DVD or Live-USB) you can do the following:

1. Boot live-system
2. Choose "Repair Your Computer" on the lower left corner
3. Look for the command prompt. It might be behind "Trying to repair windows automatically" or some like that.
4. Type `BootRec.exe /fixmbr` This will restore the Windows Boot Loader.
5. Reboot your computer to make sure it worked.